# C++, inheritance, virtual

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I've got some problems here. I' am trying to make my code working like interface in java. This class is being inherited by 2 other by they are causing some problems.
And also i'd like to know if i am doing it correctly, the ways to improve my code. I'am novice.
 Look:

Interface class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class IZarzadzaniePozycjami{

public:
    IZarzadzaniePozycjami(void);
    ~IZarzadzaniePozycjami(void);

public:
    virtual void ZnajdzPozycjePoTytule();
    virtual void ZnajdzPozycjePoId();
    virtual void WypiszWszystkiePozycje();


};

#include "Pozycja.h"
#include "IZarzadzaniePozycjami.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
```

Catalog class which inherites from IZarzadzanie... Class.

```
#include "Pozycja.h"
#include "IZarzadzaniePozycjami.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

class Katalog : public IZarzadzaniePozycjami
{
private:
    std::string dzialTematyczny;
public:
    void ZnajdzPozycjePoTytule(std::string tytul);
    void ZnajdzPozycjePoId(int id);
    void WypiszWszystkiePozycje();
    Katalog(void);
    Katalog(std::string dzialTematyczny_);
    void DodajPozycje(Pozycja);
    std::list<Pozycja> lista;
    friend bool operator==(const Katalog & kat, const std::string & s);
    ~Katalog(void);
};
inline bool operator==(std::string& s, Katalog& katalog)
{
    return katalog == s;
}
```

and then library class(biblioteka.h) which alseo inherite from interface

```
#include<iostream>
#include "IZarzadzaniePozycjami.h"
#include "Bibliotekarz.h"
#include  "Pozycja.h"
#include "Katalog.h"

class Biblioteka :
    public IZarzadzaniePozycjami
{
public:
    Biblioteka(void);
    ~Biblioteka(void);
    Biblioteka(std::string adres_);
    void DodajBibliotekarza(Bibliotekarz);
    void WypiszBibliotekarzy();
    void DodajKatalog(Katalog);
    void DodajPozycje(Pozycja p, std::string dzialTematyczny);

    void ZnajdzPozycjePoTytule(std::string tytul);
    void ZnajdzPozycjePoId(int id);
    void WypiszWszystkiePozycje();
private: std::string adres;



};
```

And here are some errors. Sorry for long post. Didn't know what to cut off.

```
c:\users\komputer\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\project1\izarzadzaniepozycjami.h(3): error C2011: 'IZarzadzaniePozycjami' : 'class' type redefinition
1>          c:\users\komputer\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\project1\izarzadzaniepozycjami.h(3) : see declaration of 'IZarzadzaniePozycjami'
1>c:\users\komputer\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\project1\katalog.h(7): error C2504: 'IZarzadzaniePozycjami' : base class undefined
1>c:\users\komputer\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\project1\biblioteka.h(9): error C2504: 'IZarzadzaniePozycjami' : base class undefined
1>  Generating Code...
1>c:\users\komputer\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\project1\katalog.cpp(16): warning C4717: 'operator==' : recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `#pragma once` in all the header files:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class IZarzadzaniePozycjami{

public:
    IZarzadzaniePozycjami(void);
    ~IZarzadzaniePozycjami(void);
....
```

and make sure the header with `IZarzadzaniePozycjami` is included everywhere before `IZarzadzaniePozycjami` is used.

Comment: Thanks! :D I thought it is some kind of how to use includes... :)

Comment: Yes, the includes are a bit strange: The declaration of a class needs to be known everywhere it is 'used', but it can only be declared once. `#pragma once` is very useful for that.

Answer (score 2):

You declare

```
virtual void ZnajdzPozycjePoTytule();
```

but in your classes you declare (and I hope you define)

```
void ZnajdzPozycjePoTytule(std::string tytul);
```

These are not the same methods. A method signature includes its parameters, so your virtual method is still unimplemented.

Answer (score 1):

What you're calling an "Interface" class is not the same as the Java concept.  In java an interface has no implementation, but the class you've defined, *must have an implementation defined*.  You can avoid defining the virtual methods if you make them pure virtual (e.g. = 0), but you *must* provide an implementation for the all non-pure virtual methods of IZarzadzaniePozycjami.  In its current form, that means every method must be defined. This is why it won't compile.

Comment: I see, whatsoever i added =0 to these functions but there are still te same errors.

Comment: You must provide a definition for all methods (including constructor and destructor) that are not =0.

Comment: Aaa can't get it working :( Made as You suggested, virtual void ZnajdzPozycjePoTytule(std::string tytul)=0;
 virtual void ZnajdzPozycjePoId(int id)=0;
 virtual void WypiszWszystkiePozycje()=0;
, double checked if anything is missing.